# Display the columns as rows with Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have the data like in the first table. And I want to display it like in the second table from the picture.

[Screenshot with the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LGmm.png)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag the bottom of the detail section lower to increase the height of the detail section.
Then, arrange the fields to your satisfaction in the detail section.
The detail section repeats once for each record.